# Using @mixin to achieve RTL support on Angular

Tags: css, angular, sass, right-to-left, left-to-right

I am using a mixin to convert my Angular app from LTR to RTL accordingly.

```
@mixin rtl($property, $ltr-value, $rtl-value) {
  [dir='ltr'] & {
    #{$property}: $ltr-value;
  }

  [dir='rtl'] & {
    #{$property}: $rtl-value;
  }
}

@mixin rtl-prop($ltr-property, $rtl-property, $value) {
  [dir='ltr'] & {
    #{$ltr-property}: $value;
  }

  [dir='rtl'] & {
    #{$rtl-property}: $value;
  }
}
```

When I use @include, for some reason it doesn't work. (html tag is defined properly)

```
@include rtl(border-radius, 0 10px 80px 0, 0 80px 10px 0);
```

```
<html lang="he" dir="rtl">
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who will encounter this issue at the future, the problem was component's encapsulation - it was set to Emulated which probably interfered with the classes names.

Set it to None instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do to solve this, but that are **not optimal**:

First and for all you are checking if the component itself has dir set, that is why it isn't working. Because the direction is set on the  tag.
You can try to use :host-context, because than it will take a look at the html attribute and not your component. Like this:

```
@mixin rtl($property, $ltr-value, $rtl-value) {
  :host-context([dir='ltr']) & {
    #{$property}: $ltr-value;
  }

  :host-context([dir='rtl']) & {
    #{$property}: $rtl-value;
  }
}
```

**But** always check on [canIUse](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahost-context) to see if it has enough coverage. For this moment it is around 75% so I would say it is too low, certainly if you have a lot of mobile iOS users.

Another alternative to :host-context() is `:dir()`, but this has on the moment of writing only 3% coverage, so I would not bother using that either.

The currently approved answer (the one that suggests to set encapsulation to None) is not recommended since it will make all the mark-up for that component global and could cause some unexpected issues. Certainly because direction is maybe something you'd want to use in almost all of your components.

---

I think the **best solution** right now is to use **logical properties** from css. You use 'start' instead of 'left' for example. You can google it and find a lot of info to use it. (for example [on developer mozilla site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties)).
For your example you would have to use:

```
.yourClass {
    border-start-start-radius: 0;
    border-start-end-radius: 10px;
    border-end-start-radius: 80px;
    border-end-end-radius: 0;
}
```

And this would make it look the way you want it on any text-direction without the use of any mixins.

Comment: Thanks but, I adjust it in order to set different properties:
```
@mixin rtl($ltr-property,$rtl-property, $ltr-value, $rtl-value) {
  :host-context([dir='ltr']) & {
    #{$ltr-property}: $ltr-value;
  }

  :host-context([dir='rtl']) & {
    #{$rtl-property}: $rtl-value;
  }
}
```